# Picking default audio output devices Debain Jessie (Alsa)

Tags: linux, audio, debian, sound-card, debian-jessie

I'm having audio issues with Debian for many months. The main problem is that i can't hear audio from the browser, but if i use VLC and i select the output device in the settings i can hear sounds.

I tried blacklisting other audio devices, changing their priority in alsa-base.conf, even installing a chromium extension to switch output device but nothing happened. How do i pick the default audio device?

Here's my /proc/asound/modules outuput:

```
0 snd_hda_intel
1 snd_usb_audio
2 snd_hda_intel
```

This is my aplay -l output:

```
saverio@Saverio-PC:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: headset [Trust GXT 363 headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The device i'm interested in is the snd_usb_audio and the card 1: headset.

Comment: Are you sure you are using only ALSA, and not Pulseaudio? Try starting `pavucontrol` while the browser is running, and switch to the correct sink in the `Playback` tab.

Comment: I deleted completely Pulseaudio some times ago because it was giving me many problems

Comment: Please edit question with contents of your `~/.asoundrc`. If you don't have one, make one and set the default device (google for instructions).

Comment: Don't put `solved` in the title. Instead, please accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a `~/.asoundrc` with the proper default device apparently solved the problem.

Comment: So what's the content of ~/.asoundrc

Comment: @holms: The original poster didn't say, but [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#An_example_of_setting_default_device_using_"defaults"_node) is how you specify the default device.

Comment: Specifying: defaults.pcm.card 1  defaults.pcm.device 0 worked